# Function with dictionary inputs and using sigma in python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, encryption

I am trying to create a function that computes the following formula:

[image]

The function takes two dictionaries as inputs and must return a positive real number.

Please help figure out how to use sigma in python and carry out this equation. Thank you in advance for your help/feedback!

Comment: Paste the sample dictionary and result you want

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan This is an example input: {'A': Fraction(48169, 599925), 'B': Fraction(8422, 599925), 'C': Fraction(4634, 199975), 'D': Fraction(9349, 199975), 'E': Fraction(74843, 599925), 'F': Fraction(13564, 599925), 'G': Fraction(12548, 599925), 'H': Fraction(1559, 23997), 'I': Fraction(41017, 599925), 'J': Fraction(238, 199975), etc. }. Both inputs are in the same format. I do not have a sample of the result I want. All I know is it must output a positive real number.

Comment: name of the above formula ..

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan I do not know the specific name of the formula, all I know is that the above formula measures how far the distribution of letters in a given text is from the distribution of letters in standard english. In brief, the formula gives the distance of frequencies.

Comment: making sigma function is not a problem but i am confused about obsx and expx

Comment: The  represents a letter in the alphabet, and i'm summing over all possible letters.  is the frequency of  observed in the string, while  is the expected frequency in the standard english dictionary. The beginning part of the standard english dictionary is pasted in the comments above.

Comment: and the second dictionary you are providing to the function is the observed one ..?

Comment: Yes, the second dictionary (observed) is computed by a separate function that counts how many times a letter occurs in a text file and returns it in the same format as the standard english dictionary (expected).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that you can use. Based on what you have said in the comments, the dictionaries must have the same keys, and based on that assumption this function should do the job:

```
def calculate_distance(obs_dict, exp_dict):
    distance = 0
    for key in obs_dict.keys():
        distance += (obs_dict[key] - exp_dict[key]) ** 2 / exp_dict[key]
    return distance
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!